# How to save listView in shared preferences (android)

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences

I want to save elements of list in sharedPreferences. I know sharedPreferences saved only simple data. Is it posibble?

my Activity class:

```
List<String> tasks;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_sms_number);

    tasks = new ArrayList<String>();

    Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,tasks);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(editText, 0);

            String value = editText.getText().toString();
            tasks.add(value);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: You can store your List as a Set, and then convert it back to a List when you read from SharedPreferences.

Comment: Can you show me how it should look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can store your List as a Set, and then convert it back to a List when you read from SharedPreferences.  Note: this doesn't work if your Strings need to be ordered specifically, obviously.

```
tasksList = new ArrayList<String>();
Set<String> tasksSet = new HashSet<String>(tasksList);
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    .edit()
    .putStringSet("tasks_set", tasksSet)
    .commit();
```

Then when you read it:

```
Set<String> tasksSet = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    .getStringSet("tasks_set", new HashSet<String>());
List<String> tasksList = new ArrayList<String>(tasksSet);
```