# Reload ListView in same activity

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to populate a `listview` using custom adapter and saving it using `shared preferences` as shown below.

**Saving List:**

```
Set<String> mycategory = new HashSet<String>(MyCategory);
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(CategoryList.this)
    .edit()
    .putStringSet("MyCategory", mycategory)
    .commit();
```

**Retreiving List:**

```
  Set<String> mycategory = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AddItems.this)
    .getStringSet("MyCategory", new HashSet<String>());
     ArrayList<String> CategoryList = new ArrayList<String>(mycategory);
    MyAddedList.addAll(CategoryList);
    adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

My Scenario: First Clicking a button in `MainActivity` which goes to `second activity` where I have a `button` in second activity which can add some items to my listview which works pretty well and now If I navigate using up enabled `home button` to MainActivity and If I get back to the second activity the list is `empty`.

So now how do I `retain` the data though If I come back to the `same` activity..

I don't want to use any db but would like to know using sharedpreferences.

EDIT:

I'm calling this in a dialog when button is Clicked:

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemscategoryView);
    adp = new MyCategoryAdapter(CategoryList.this, MyCategory);
    /*
     * adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>( MainActivity.this, R.layout.list,
     * R.id.textView, MyList);
     */
    lv.setAdapter(adp);
    // setup a dialog window
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    String NewListname = editText.getText().toString();

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(NewListname)) {
                        return;
                    } else {
                        //mylistitem = NewListname;
                        MyCategory.add(NewListname);
                        adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    Set<String> mycategory = new HashSet<String>(MyCategory);
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name),MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putStringSet("MyCategory", mycategory);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

    // create an alert dialog
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();

}
```

OnResume:

```
  @Override
        public void onResume(){
            super.onResume();
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name),MODE_PRIVATE);
                Set<String> mycategory = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("MyCategory", new HashSet<String>());
                MyCategory.addAll(mycategory);
        }
```

Comment: This could be caused because the second activity is still alive. What about load Your list again in onResume()? Or call finish() in the second activity when You go back to main...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs-tried but didn't not load the list again

Comment: Im sure you pasted the wrong code. But here you are only saving the list, your retrieve is the same as saving.

Comment: Unless you've got a typo in your code block, you're using `putStringSet(...)` when retrieving.

Comment: @Squonk-ah srry..its a typo mistake.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/23900033/3843374

Comment: @Paritosh- Exactly..that is what I have used..I dont have problem in storing or retrieving but getting back the list in the same activity is what I would like to know

Comment: could You post the complete code, so we can see where You load the prefs?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs-Updated code. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use application SharedPreferences instead getDefaultSharedPreferences :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name),MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putStringSet("MyCategory", mycategory);
editor.commit();

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name),MODE_PRIVATE);
Set<String> mycategory = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("MyCategory", new HashSet<String>());
```

Comment: @Haresh-Where do I ned to add these ? In Onresume of second Activity ?

Comment: Yes get String Set in OnResume and have you update String Set in SharedPreferences when new item added ?

Comment: Yes its working but When I click the button on the second activity its loading the list but I want it to load as soon as the activity loads

Answer (score 0):

On back press of the second activity first clear the shared preference and again set the  updated Set mycategory to shared preference and in first activity override the onResume method and their you set the list adapter again